# converting and Separating 2 byte hex to two chararacters, upper two hex goes to one character and lower two hex goes to second charater in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, console-application, hex

I have an unsigned int value in

```
u_int_variable = 43981; // This is equal to ABCD in HEX
```

I can print this to console in hex as ABCD using

```
printf("Value in Hex is %X", u_int_variable);

// Output : Value in Hex is ABCD
```

How can I convert and separate this such that

```
unsigned char uhex, lhex;

uhex = 0xAB; and lhex = 0xCD;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uhex = static_cast<unsigned char>(u_int_variable >> 8);
lhex = static_cast<unsigned char>(u_int_variable & 0xFF);
```

Or, to be absolutely safe for >32 bit unsigned ints:

```
uhex = static_cast<unsigned char>((u_int_variable >> 8) & 0xFF);
```

Answer (score 1):

As variant:

```
unsigned char uhex, lhex;
lhex = static_cast<unsigned char>( u_int_variable & 0xFF );
uhex = static_cast<unsigned char>( (u_int_variable >> 8) & 0xFF );
```

Good first-depth article about bitwise operations is [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

I offer you to use **bit-fields** and **unions**, solution will look smth like this:

```
struct hex
    {
        unsigned int lhex : 8; // upper and lower part alignement are system dependent
        unsigned int uhex : 8;
    };

    union number
    {
        number(int val): m_val(val){};
        void lhex(void) {printf("lhex %X", this->num.lhex);};
        void uhex(void) {printf("uhex %X", this->num.uhex);};
        int m_val;
        hex num;
    };

    number n(43981);
    n.lhex();
    n.uhex();
```